# Use of Cascade and Inverse

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I read here [What is the difference between cascade & inverse in hibernate, what are they used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3667387/1564528) that

"In case of many-to-many relation through intermediary table; "Cascade" says whether record will be created/updated in child table. Whereas "Inverse" says whether record will be created/updated in intermediary table"

and the explanation was really good, I got it .. But this is many-to-many case.what is the use of cascade and inverse (or what is the difference between Cascade and inverse) in case of one-to-many and many-one relationships?

Answer (score 1):

In case of one-to-many relation:

- "Cascade" says whether the operation (save/update/delete/refresh...) will also be invoked on the childs
- "Inverse" says whether the foreign key column will be set/updated by the entity containing the collection or not. Inverse="true" assumes that the child object has a backreference and the child will set/update the foreignkeycolumn when it is saved/updated